# Random number from given numbers in structure C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have my structure set up like this

```
struct judges
{
    char surname[20];
    int id;
    struct judges *wsk;
}
```

How can I get random number from given IDs? Like for example, I add 3 judges with IDs 3, 7, and 253, is there a way to get random number only from these ones?

Comment: Build an array containing the IDs, generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array, and use that number as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a random item from an array of these structures and read its ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `srand()` to set your random seed (in this case ID) then use `rand()` to get your random number for each judge. also you can use [Glib Random Number(https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-Random-Numbers.html) instead of standard C function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pick a random number from the array.
But to pick one within your array, you must use:

```
rand() % arrayLength;
//in your case:
rand() % 3; //returns 0,1,or 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main(){
       struct judges judge;
       int index,i;
       time_t t;
       srand((unsigned int)time(&t));

       int ids[]={3,7,253};
       index=rand() % 3;
       judge.id=ids[index];
}
```

You need to build an array of ids, and then generate a random index using srand() and rand() and assign it to judge.id field.

---

if you want more information about random numbers generating http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm